# How to buy Steam Keys on Steam?

Tags: steam

Is there a method to buy game keys on Steam? I saw that a few games were onsale and thought that maybe I could buy them and resell them later. All the other methods I've seen are also outdated... Send help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to purchase a game for someone else is [Steam Gift](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#gifts-whatare).

You won't be able to sell it using steam market, attempts to sell gifts also  violate [steam rules](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#sellgifts):

> Attempting to sell a gift subscription is a violation of the Steam Subscriber Agreement and may result in your account being permanently disabled.